# How to upload file to Dropbox?

Tags: java, dropbox

I want to upload a file to drop-box using a web-application. But the problem is that Java is asking the complete file path. What do I have to do? This is my code:

```
File inputFile = new File("D://New Text Document.txt");
System.out.println("inputFile.getAbsoluteFile(): " + inputFile);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D://New Text Document.txt");

try {
    DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
    DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
    System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

In the first line it is asking for the file path; how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative path

```
File inputFile = new File("working-draft.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
try {
DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
    DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
} finally {
inputStream.close();
}
```

[more details here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java)

Comment: if i give relative path  it is showing error like file not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dropbox Java Core SDK tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java#uploading) has the following code as a sample for uploading a file:

```
File inputFile = new File("working-draft.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
try {
    DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
        DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
    System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

In the sample above, in the first line, "working-draft.txt" is the local path to a local file. This needs to point to an existing local file. Your code has "D://New Text Document.txt" so you should first make sure there is actually a file there.

In the fourth line, "/magnum-opus.txt", the first parameter passed to `uploadFile`, is the desired remote path, that is, where in the Dropbox folder you want to upload the file to. The API requires remote paths be referenced relatively like this. The `uploadFile` method is documented [here](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#uploadFile(java.lang.String,%20com.dropbox.core.DbxWriteMode,%20long,%20java.io.InputStream)).

Comment: I agree with that.In webapplication we didn't get file path that it is comming through network.So i can get only file name.How can i pass file-path to drop-box?

Comment: If you're referring to the local path, the uploadFile method just takes an InputStream for the data you want to upload. The sample here happens to create an InputStrem from a local file, referenced by path, but any InputStream would work. If you're referring to the remote path, it's just whatever you choose, and you can just include the full path. E.g., you can upload into specific folders like "/Documents/Working/magnum-opus.txt".